# "The main reason that online shopping is so appealing and developing so fast is its convenience." Why uses "developing" but not "develops"?

Tags: grammar

In my thought, it's natural to say that

1. The main reason that online shopping is so appealing is its convenience.
2. The main reason that online shopping develops so fast is its convenience.

So why use "developing" when combine the above two sentences?

Also, I am confused about the pronoun "its", since in my mind I subsect the sentence into
"The main reason | that online shopping is so appealing and developing so fast | is its convenience." So I think "its" is something "out of scope".

Comment: There's nothing at all "incorrect" about using Simple Present rather than *progressive* verb forms in the cited context. It's just that *stylistically*, a progressive / continuous verb adds "immediacy" to the text - which is good, because it's about *something that is **happening** [now]* (as opposed to "something that happens", which is a lot more vague).

Comment: There's nothing grammatically wrong with either form, but they mean different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 2 should be "The main reason that online shopping is developing so quickly is its convenience."

First note that "fast" is incorrect (but common and colloquial). The adverb is "quickly".

"Online shopping is developing fast" means "at this point in time, online shopping is developing quickly".

But "online shopping develops fast" means "it is the nature of online shopping to develop quickly". That is, "online shopping is always going to develop quickly."

But it is only *now* that online shopping is developing quickly. It won't always be the case; sooner or later it will reach saturation.

You are correct about the "its", but it is a minor point. It is technically incorrect, but should not result in confusion.

"The main reason for the appeal and fast development of online shopping is its convenience" should avoid that, but it loses the immediacy and readability of the original sentence.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a problem with ***its*** in the cited context. The convenience of online shopping ***is*** "its convenience". What's (technically?) wrong with that?

Comment: The structure of the sentence is such that "its" technically attaches itself to "the main reason".

Comment: I don't think so! Consider essentially the same structure, slightly simplified: *The reason Jane is so fat is her diet.* Clearly ***her*** references ***Jane***, in exactly the same way ***its*** references ***online shopping*** in OP's example. I can't see *any* non-trivial rephrasing that could allow ***its*** to reference ***the main reason***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Yes, but while colloquial, it's technically ungrammatical.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "technically ungrammatical" there, but I think you're mistaken. Whatever - I doubt either of us will convince the other, so we should leave it at that.